# How to select the first row of a specific column in a list in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following code. Please see the explanation in ###. Data is two columns with Time and velocity at 10Hz sampling rate

| Time | velocity |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0000000 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.0099998 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.0200003 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.0300001 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.0399999 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.0499997 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.0600002 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.0700000 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.0799998 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.0900003 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.1000001 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.1099999 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.1199997 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.1300002 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.1400000 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.1499998 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.1600003 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.1700001 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.1799999 | 0.3444447 |
| 0.1899997 | 0.4416670 |
| 0.2000002 | 0.4416670 |
| 0.2100000 | 0.4416670 |
| 0.2199998 | 0.4416670 |
| 0.2300003 | 0.4416670 |
| 0.2400001 | 0.6222227 |
| 0.2499999 | 0.6222227 |
| 0.2599997 | 0.6222227 |

... and so on

```
#create interval 
  from=min(data$Time)
  to=max(data$Time)
  breaks=seq(from, to, by=0.2)
  
  
  #function to select values in each interval and create a list, I am trying to find the highest velocity value in each interval of time BUT only IF it is greater than the value in the previous time interval 
  
  interval <- lapply(1:(length(breaks)-1L), function(i) {
    x <- subset(sprint1, Time >= breaks[i] & Time <= breaks[i+1L])
    x[x$velocity == max(x$velocity[1]), ]
  })
  
  #function to round values to two decimal places
  r <- function(x) format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2L)
  
  #assign names to each element of interval
  for(i in seq_along(interval)) {
    names(interval)[i] <- paste0(r(breaks[i]), '-', r(breaks[i+1L]))
  }
  
  
  interval ##output
```

You can create dataset with Time and velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a list or loop. Here's my suggestion, based on my understanding of your issue:

First, define your intervals based on breaks using `cut()`:

```
library(dplyr)

# Define breaks for intervals ("groups")
breaks <- seq(0, 0.28, by = 0.02)

# Group data using breaks
dat$interval <- cut(dat$Time, breaks = breaks, right = FALSE, labels = FALSE)
```

Now use dplyr to manipulate your data based on your condition: "find the highest velocity value in each interval of time BUT only IF it is greater than the value in the previous time interval."

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  # For each group, as defined by an interval
  group_by(interval) %>%
  # Get the maximum velocity value
  mutate(interval_max = max(velocity)) %>%
  # Now ungroup and iterate across rows
  ungroup %>%
  # If the previous value is greater than the current value,
  # keep the previous value, if not, keep the current value
  mutate(interval_max_cond = ifelse(
                                 lag(interval_max) > interval_max,
                                 lag(interval_max),
                                 interval_max))
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

data:

```
dat <- structure(list(Time = c(0, 0.0099998, 0.0200003, 0.0300001, 0.0399999, 
0.0499997, 0.0600002, 0.07, 0.0799998, 0.0900003, 0.1000001, 
0.1099999, 0.1199997, 0.1300002, 0.14, 0.1499998, 0.1600003, 
0.1700001, 0.1799999, 0.1899997, 0.2000002, 0.21, 0.2199998, 
0.2300003, 0.2400001, 0.2499999, 0.2599997), velocity = c(0.3444447, 
0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 
0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 
0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 0.3444447, 
0.441667, 0.441667, 0.441667, 0.441667, 0.441667, 0.6222227, 
0.6222227, 0.6222227)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-27L))
```

Comment: Thank you and I really like the logic here. Way simpler. Will this work with a tibble dataframe? I have tried your example with my dataframe and there is no error showing but there apears to be no change in the data after this code is applied. @Skaqqs

Comment: Yes, it should work with a tibble. If you copy and pasted my code directly, the result will be printed in the console. Can you see it there? Run it line by line and look at the result of each.

Comment: I can see it in the console, but it is returning the exact same tibble dataframe "dat"

Comment: Hi again - try it with the example data that you shared in your question. It works on my side, which suggests there are differences between the example dataset you shared and your actual data. Unfortunately I can't help troubleshoot without seeing more data and/or the code you're using on your side. Is the field "interval" present and correct? Are the field names identical (note Time is capitalized and velocity is not)? Did you try assigning the results of the dplyr chain to a new object, eg `dat2 <- dat %>% ...`?

Comment: Worked perfectly! just had to add newdat <- dat %>% etc. ... Thank you very much Skaqqs